# Start loading screen when function start and end loading screen when done. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript app. i want to show the loading screen before i start doing something and stop loading screen when something done. here my code.

```
btn_start.addEventListener('click',function(){
    $('#loading-screen').show(); 
    //do something (example i do function in object)
    the_object.startFuntion(param1);
    $('#loading-screen').hide();
});
```

if i use that code, the loading screen doesnt appear, so the app like pause sometime then the_object.startFunction(param1) just done without loading screen.

UPDATE :
the div lookslike this

```
<div id="loading-screen">
    <img src="img/loading.gif" id="img-loading">
</div>
```

actually i try to generating word search board (in word search game). There's many process before showing the board so, i tried to show loading screen when it generating the board.

here the css of loading screen :

```
#loading-screen{ 
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index : 1000;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  display: none;
}

#loading-screen:before {   
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 100%;
}

#img-loading{
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin:auto;    
}
```

Comment: Here's how this executes once the button is clicked: 1. show loading screen; 2. do whatever startFunction does; 3. hide the loading screen. This all happens immediately, if you're kicking of some asynchronous things then you'll need to pass a callback along to hide the loading screen, otherwise it will just be hidden immediately.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, do you have some example of asynchronous things?

Comment: @FerryGideon try with snippet I added with setTimeout.

Comment: @FerryGideon what are you doing in your start function? Are you requesting any additional content via AJAX?

Comment: Also, what does your HTML look like, if you're saying even with a setTimeout the loading screen doesn't show, maybe something else is going on. Try to give us the minimum necessary code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TechBreak i've tried but i doenst work for my case.

Comment: @Dymos i dont requesting AJAX, i just try to generating board on for word search game. so there are so many process to do i think and held random time may be 5-15 second.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setTimeout function otherwise it will be instant effect because .hide() wouldn't normally be applied the animation objects.

```
btn_start.addEventListener('click',function(){
    $('#loading-screen').show('slow'); 
    //do something (example i do function in object)
    the_object.startFuntion(param1);
   setTimeout(function() { $('#loading-screen').hide('slow'); }, 5000);
});
```

Your html should be as follows and try adding slow animation to check more into it

```
<div id="loading-screen" style="display: none">
  <img src="img/loading.gif" id="img-loading">
</div>
```

Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/4t3mLjxz/2/

Comment: i've tried to add timeout like you did, but loading screen doesnt even show. actually the_object.startFunction(params1) have random time to be done.

Comment: Please can you add your html code for loading-screen?

Comment: @FerryGideon try adding hide class or <div id="loading-screen" style="display: none"> on your div.